# ear deployment from IDE fails, maven command-line build works

Tags: maven, jakarta-ee, m2eclipse, jboss-eap-7, jboss-developer-studio

I have a pretty standard ear project trying to migrate from Weblogic to JBoss EAP 7.  I have the following artifacts:

ear file
war file
ejb-jar file
ebj-client file ( local interfaces)

When I build the project from the command line with "mvn clean install" then deploy to eap, it loads just fine.  If I open the same maven project and import into jboss developer studio, when I attempt to deploy/run on server from the IDE, I get a bunch of class not found errors:

```
"WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {
    "jboss.deployment.subunit.\"HansenIntegtationFramework.ear\".\"HansenIntegrationFramework-ejb-1.0.jar\".INSTALL" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.subunit.\"HansenIntegtationFramework.ear\".\"HansenIntegrationFramework-ejb-1.0.jar\".INSTALL: WFLYSRV0153: Failed to process phase INSTALL of subdeployment \"HansenIntegrationFramework-ejb-1.0.jar\" of deployment \"HansenIntegtationFramework.ear\"
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed to link com/hsntech/hif/logging/HIFLogData (Module \"deployment.HansenIntegtationFramework.ear:main\" from Service Module Loader): org/apache/logging/log4j/message/MapMessage",
    "jboss.deployment.subunit.\"HansenIntegtationFramework.ear\".\"HansenIntegrationFramework-web-1.0.war\".INSTALL" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.subunit.\"HansenIntegtationFramework.ear\".\"HansenIntegrationFramework-web-1.0.war\".INSTALL: WFLYSRV0153: Failed to process phase INSTALL of subdeployment \"HansenIntegrationFramework-web-1.0.war\" of deployment \"HansenIntegtationFramework.ear\"
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/logging/log4j/Logger
```

Any suggestions on how to approach this?  Why is the IDE behaving differently?

UPDATE:  I found the problem, but not sure how to fix it.  IDE is not copying dependant jar files into the jboss deployment's lib folder.  maven command line install does.  Any clues?

Comment: It looks like maybe the IDE isn't building the EAR correctly. I've seen issues before where that happens because they try to incrementally build the deployment.

Comment: James R. Perkins may be right. OldProgrammer, but may i ask you, please, to provide a simple project (e.g. a link to github) which can be used to replicate your problem?

Comment: I switched back to netbeans, and problem went away

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to https://github.com/jboss-developer/jboss-eap-quickstarts/tree/7.0.x/log4j as a starter on how to use Log4J on EAP 7.0

Comment: Thanks, but does not really address my issue.  I am using slf4j over log4j2.  maven deploy works fine.  run from IDE does not.